# Photoshop GPU Sniffer uses %50 of cpu even when photoshop is closed

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have photoshop cc,
Weirdly, the Photoshop GPU Sniffer has two instances, and both use %20 each even when photoshop is closed.

How can I fix this? Is this a bug?

Ps. Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This might be due to font corruption. try disabling FontExplorer and check whether it fixes the issue

Comment: For me, updating the graphics driver was the answer - now that my driver is up to date, Photoshop detects it, properly enables hardware acceleration and stops running the sniffer.

Comment: How strange, I never realised not all locales have the percent sign on the right...